# localstorage is not working in Windows phone PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone, local-storage

I am developing a Windows Phone PhoneGap app. `localStorage` is not defined outside of the `onDeviceReady` function. I tried including modernizr.js. As I have many HTML files, it is not possible to include the `onDeviceReady` function to make it work. So, `localStorage` is not working in those html files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @Raoul George yes I am using jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and referencing the jQuery Mobile library directly from your project directory.

```
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2427)

Comment: I am already using <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> only.

Comment: Ok, is the localstorage accessible from within the ondeviceready function?

Comment: Ideally, all your javascript code should be called only after the onDeviceReady event is fired. Is there any reason you are trying to do it before the event fires?

Comment: No. actually I have multiple HTML files. ondeviceready function can be there in one HTML file only. That is the issue.

Comment: If you are developing a multipage application with phonegap, then you probably need to load phonegap on each of these pages seperately in order to trigger the onDeviceReady event on each of these pages. This will definitely affect performance as Phonegap has to be loaded on each of your pages. Have you thought about using a single page application? Jquery mobile works well with them.